# Android: Signed APK issue - no default constructor when there is one

Tags: android

I'm getting the

```
'This class should provide a default constructor'
```

error when i'm trying to build the APK

this is my DBHelper class:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// create variables
public DBHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
}
// onCreate
```

I was under the impression that

```
public DBHelper(Context context)
```

was the default constructor? And have checked other answers with this and can't find anything to help...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Comment: what version of gradle/android studio are you using ?

Comment: Are you getting the error during build or when running the app?

Comment: Newest android studio i think? 
No errors running the app - just when trying to create a signed APK - unless there is a way to just take the APK that's created when the application is run ?

Comment: Nicopico's answer gives a lot more sense though; SQLiteOpenHelper needs Context to work. OTOH, Fragment needs empty constructor to work, but since you already accepted the other answer, then I might be wrong...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the error suggest

> Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)

try this way:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// create variables

public DBHelper(){
    super();
}

public DBHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
}



// onCreate
```

Comment: I had to add this to it though:
`public DBHelper(){ 
  super(null, null, null, 1);
}`
Just for anyone else that might have issues :)

Comment: If you pass `null` as the first parameter in `super(...)`, your app has a good chance to crash with a `NullPointerException`

Comment: I never implement empty constructor for SQLiteOpenHelper, so I doubt this... unless there's something that OP hasn't mentioned.

Comment: I just gave answer to this error `This class should provide a default constructor` And it helped the OP. `accepted answers are not the best answer they denoted that they had helped the OP`

Answer (score 2):

A default constructor is a constructor without any arguments.

`SQLiteOpenHelper` needs at least a context so you won't be able to create a default constructor for your `DBHelper`. Are you sure this is the class causing this error ?